Issue with View function and strange vector(?) output in R
I am using R (version 4.4.0) to analyze a giant medical electronic health record-based dataset with > 100,000,000 observations. I am trying to examine the health disparities associated with race/ethnicity. I have a race and ethnicity variable that was derived from a survey. It is my understanding that respondents could choose as many race or ethnicity categories as they wanted. I am able to work with the respondents who chose only 1 race/ethnicity. However, I am having trouble with those who selected 2 or more categories. I used the View(df) function, and I replicated an example of the output below:



ID
RaceEthnicity




1001
c("RaceEthnicity: White", "RaceEthnicity: Hispanic", "RaceEthnicity: Asian")


1003
c("RaceEthnicity: Asian", "RaceEthnicity: Black")



Here is the sublet dput function output:
structure(list(person_id = c(1001, 1003), `raceethnicityanswer` = list(
  c("Race Ethnicity: White", "Race Ethnicity: Hispanic", "Race Ethnicity: Asian"
  ), c("Race Ethnicity: Asian", "Race Ethnicity: Black"
  ))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
  ))

I am trying to develop a variable that encompasses everybody's race/ethnicity by using the mutate function. However, I am having extreme difficulty with "naming" the output for people who have 2 or more race/ethnicity categories in the RaceEthnicity column because it has the weird "c(" thing instead of just listing "RaceEthnicity: Hispanic" like it does for respondents who have only 1 category selected (is that called a vector?). Here is output that I have tried. While the mutate function statements all "work" in R (i.e., there is no "error" message that appears), when I use the table function (table(df$RaceEth)), it says: "< table of extent 0 >" even though there should be some table output.
#Attempt 1#
df <- mutate(df,
            RaceEth = case_when(str_detect(df$raceethnicityanswer, "c('RaceEthnicity: White'") ~ "White",
                                str_detect(df$raceethnicityanswer, "c('RaceEthnicity: Hispanic'") ~ "Hispanic",
                                ))

#Attempt 2#
df <- mutate(df, 
            RaceEth = case_when(str_detect(df$raceethnicityanswer, "c('RaceEthnicity") ~ "Other",
                                ))

#Attempt 3#
df <- mutate(df,
            RaceEth = case_when(
              df$raceethnicityanswer == "c('RaceEthnicity: White', 'RaceEthnicity: Hispanic', 'RaceEthnicity: Asian')" ~ "White, Hispanic, Asian"
              df$raceethnicityanswer == "c('RaceEthnicity: Asian', 'RaceEthnicity: Black')" ~ "Asian, Black"
            ))

#Attempt 4#
df <- mutate(df,
            RaceEth = case_when(
              df$raceethnicityanswer == "c('RaceEthnicity: White', 'RaceEthnicity: Hispanic', 'RaceEthnicity: Asian')" ~ "Other"
              df$raceethnicityanswer == "c('RaceEthnicity: Asian', 'RaceEthnicity: Black')" ~ "Other"
            ))

#Attempt 5#
df <- mutate(df,
            RaceEth = case_when(
              df$raceethnicityanswer == "'RaceEthnicity: White', 'RaceEthnicity: Hispanic', 'RaceEthnicity: Asian'" ~ "Other"
              df$raceethnicityanswer == "'RaceEthnicity: Asian', 'RaceEthnicity: Black'" ~ "Other"
            ))

#Attempt 6#
df <- mutate(df,
            RaceEth = case_when(
              df$raceethnicityanswer == "RaceEthnicity: White, RaceEthnicity: Hispanic, RaceEthnicity: Asian" ~ "Other"
              df$raceethnicityanswer == "RaceEthnicity: Asian, RaceEthnicity: Black" ~ "Other"
            ))

How do I call/refer to this vectorized(?) output in a mutate function? Hopefully this made sense, happy to clarify any questions. Thank you for your help!

You have a nested list in your race/ethnicity column. You can use purrr::map_chr within mutate to apply the sub and paste functions to the list get rid of the unwanted text and extract everything into a single column:
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(raceethnicityanswer = purrr::map_chr(raceethnicityanswer, ~ 
                                         paste(sub("Race Ethnicity: ", "", .x), collapse = ", ")))

Or even more elegantly using toString, thanks to @Friede:
df %>%
  mutate(raceethnicityanswer = purrr::map_chr(raceethnicityanswer, ~ 
                                                toString(sub("Race Ethnicity: ", "", .x))))

Both output:
# person_id raceethnicityanswer   
#       <dbl> <chr>                 
# 1      1001 White, Hispanic, Asian
# 2      1003 Asian, Black  


Here I make another attempt. You can use unnest_longer() from tidyr and set transform parameter to remove unneeded texts.
df %>%
  tidyr::unnest_longer(raceethnicityanswer, transform = ~ sub("Race Ethnicity: ", "", .x)) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(raceethnicityanswer = toString(raceethnicityanswer), .by = person_id)

# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   person_id raceethnicityanswer   
#       <dbl> <chr>                 
# 1      1001 White, Hispanic, Asian
# 2      1003 Asian, Black

This is a tidyr-only solution.
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unnest_longer(raceethnicityanswer, transform = ~ sub("Race Ethnicity: ", "", .x)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = raceethnicityanswer, values_from = raceethnicityanswer) %>%
  unite(raceethnicityanswer, -person_id, sep = ', ', na.rm = TRUE)


In base, a careful data-transformation without the use of unlist() might involve vapply() like
# df0 := df (I do not use df)
df0$raceethnicityanswer = 
  vapply(df0$raceethnicityanswer, 
       \(i) toString(sub("Race Ethnicity: ", "", i)), character(1L))

giving
> df0
person_id    raceethnicityanswer
1      1001 White, Hispanic, Asian
2      1003           Asian, Black

> sapply(df0, class)
 person_id raceethnicityanswer 
 "numeric"         "character" 

Why to use vapply? See e.g. this SO discussion.
